# Onclick function pug from node

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I passed function to render in my pug file. What I want is when the button is clicked, the function should start, but the function starts when I enter the site. Below is how I passed function and using this in PUG file

Router

```
const start = require('../bot')

exports.home = (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', {
        functionOne: start.mainFunction()
    });
 }
```

PUG File

```
html
    head
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,700")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css")
    body
        button(type="button" id="mybutton" onclick="functionOne")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The res.render statement is only meant to send data to the template, you can't send a function through there.  The [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) explains this.

The function is running when you request the page because that's actually what you're telling it to do when you include that function in there.

You will need to write some client-side JavaScript to make an AJAX call or form POST then create a new ExpressJS route on the server to capture that and run the function.